# Static reflection for Protobuf in C++

Tags: c++, reflection, protocol-buffers, static-reflection

This is a bit of a "moon shot", but still: does the C++ Protobuf implementation support "static reflection"; or is there a way to make this work?

My goal is to have an API e.g. like this:

```cpp
template<typename ProtobufMsg, typename MemberType, typename... PbMemberName>
MemberType& get_pb_mutable_ref(ProtobufMsg &msg, PbMemberName... path_elements);
```

So that I can call it e.g. like this:

```cpp
auto &member_ref = get_pb_mutable_ref(my_pb_msg, "member_x", "sub_member_y");
member_ref = "abc";
```

The `get_pb_mutable_ref()` call would return a mutable reference, as if I had called `my_pb_msg->mutable_member_x()->mutable_sub_member_y()`.

The type of `member_ref` should be deduced at compile time; and if the specified `path_elements` do not lead to a valid member, a compiler error should be raised.

Background: I want to use such an API to create helper functions through which members can be modified (with compile-time checking), so that the helper function can intercept and record the change.

Answer (score 2):

That cannot work. C++ cannot deduce `MemberType`. Furthermore, `PbMemberName` would easily be deduced as a list of `const char*`, there's no need to have that as a template parameter

C++ Template Argument Deduction is based on the type of the function call expression, not the actual arguments. In this example, that signature would be `(ProtobufMsg, const char*, const char*)`. This information does not include `"member_x", "sub_member_y"`

You would need something like `&ProtobufMsg::member_x` and `ProtobufMsg::PartX::sub_member_y`, which would be strongly typed pointers to members.

Comment: Ok, makes sense to me. Based on your last paragraph I built a function now that can be called like `auto &member_ref = get_pb_mutable_ref(my_pb_msg, PbMainMsg::mutable_member_x, SubPbMsg::mutable_sub_member_y);`. I works, but is too cumbersome for my taste; and I don't see a way to shorten it.